# Make shift key behave like on the iPhone

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, shift, sticky-keys

On the iPhone, after pressing the <kbd>shift</kbd> key, the next letter will be capitalised regardless of whether <kbd>shift</kbd> is held down or not.
Is there a way to make the shift key on my mac behave similarly?

I am already using Karabiner for some custom modifications, but I have not found this functionality.

The solution could either involve Karabiner, some other app or just macOS settings.

Comment: Is your CAPS LOCK key broken?

Comment: Caps Lock does not behave in the way I am describing here. With Caps Lock, I would need to press it again after pressing the capitalised letter so the next letters are in lowercase.

Comment: Indeed. CAPS LOCK and SHIFT work that way in any desktop or laptop computer. What you want can't be done because SHIFT is a "dead key" in any physical keyboard. On-screen keyboards, including those apps for desktop OSes like MacOS, Windows and thousands of Linux distros, do act like you want and have to because it wouldn't make sense otherwise.

Comment: @ChanganAuto that's true for a normal environment, but in accessibility mode it's possible to change the behavior of modifier keys to what the OP wants. And it's not "dead" because dead keys will produce a character when combining or followed by another character

Comment: @phuclv Agree with the first part/sentence. Disagree with the rest: The very definition of "dead keys" is keys that do nothing by themselves but often do "something" when combined.

Comment: @ChanganAuto a dead key ... [*is typically used to attach a specific diacritic to a base letter.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's called [sticky keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_keys). Just go to *Preferences > Accessibility > Keyboard* and check *"Enable Sticky Keys"*

[image: Sticky keys preferences]

But of course it'll just affect the next input key. To enter all following characters as upper case you obviously need to use <kbd>caps lock</kbd>

Comment: Thank you! This was what I was looking for!